# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes issue

Tags: freeze, 20.04

I'm running 20.04 on my desktop (with Nvidia 2080 super and Nvidia 440 driver) and it often freezes. I am suppose there could be an issue the bluetooth driver, or there could be an issue with gcc related packages? Because my bluetooth sometimes turns off by itself, and I'm using build-essential packages to compile some packages in c++. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, there is a conflict between the open-source driver with that of the graphic card from Nvidia. I will write down the solution that worked for me, on a Lenovo ThinkPad P53 when installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I faced some issues.

Follow the steps written below:

1. Boot to Ubuntu, but before you login in to Ubuntu, press Cntrl+Alt+F2
2. run the following command:

   ```
        sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
   ```
3. add the 2 following lines, save & exit

   ```
        blacklist nouveau
        options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
4. run the following command

   ```
        sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

Comment: Could you explain the meaning of your commands? Thanks!